# Registering Laravel middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

Just starting to get into laravel and running into major issues migrating my vanilla `php` to use it.

I created a `middleware`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Session;

class QwickAuthCheck
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->session()->has('qwick')) {
            //
            return redirect('home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I'm checking to see if a session is set.
`home` is a route I have in `routes.php`

```
Route::get('/', 'WebController@home')->name('home');
```

I register it in `kernel.php` like so;

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ........
    ........
    'qwickAuth' => \App\Http\Middleware\QwickAuthCheck::class,
];
```

Now I want to apply the `middleware` to

```
Route::get('login', 'WebController@login');
```

How can I do this?

I have tried;

```
Route::get('login', ['middleware' => ['qwickAuth'], 'WebController@login');
```

Laravel has a lot of documentation on their site but for some reason all their code is not giving snippets of how people use this framework. In the middleware documentation all they gave was this;

```
Route::get('admin/profile', ['middleware' => 'auth', function () {
    //
}]);
```

How do I know how to use it seeing that I don't have a `function` in my route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
Route::get('login', ['middleware' => ['qwickAuth'], 'uses' =>'WebController@login']);
```

You have example of `uses` in routing here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes

Answer (score 2):

While Marcins result works, you can also do it this way

```
Route::get('login', 'WebController@login')->middleware(['qwickAuth']);
```